# Accessing array elements in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a number of rows like this:

```
<tr>        
    <TD class="Lo">90%</TD>                        
    <TD class="Poor">80%</TD>                   
    <TD class="Lo">89%</TD>                     
    <TD class="Mid">85%</TD>                        
    <TD class="Poor">85%</TD>                       
    <TD class="Mid">85%</TD>                        
    <TD class="Hi">85%</TD>
</tr>
```

Now I want to access any elements in this row and set the color of that row based on values:

- If the 80% < value <= 85% colours yellow,
- If the 90% < value <= 95% colours red,
- If the 95% < value <= 100% colours green.

How to do this using jQuery?

Comment: It'd be good to provide the html with <table /> as well since table may have an id that can be used as a selector for intended highlighting.

Comment: It's been a few days, how about choosing one of the answers?

Answer (score 3):

You might get some good use out of making a few [custom selectors](http://debuggable.com/posts/getting-serious-with-jquery-adding-custom-css-selectors:480f4dd6-e834-4cf6-a5cc-478ccbdd56cb) for this.

For example, here's one called "high":

```
jQuery.expr[':'].high = '(put your boolean logic here, inside quotes)';
```

Then, after you have your custom selectors, do this for each one:

```
$('td:high').css('color', 'green');
```

Comment: That's a very elegant solution. :)

Comment: This requires some logic on the names of the element classes though.

Comment: @codemeit no it doesn't rely on the class at all.   The selector can simply check the contents of the tag, or do anything else you are allowed to do in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$("td").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().replace('%') <= 90) {
    $(this).css('background','red');
  } else if ($(this).text().replace('%') <= 100) {
    $(this).css('background','green');
  }
  // repeat ...
});
```

Comment: This will always make it green since all values are less than 100

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution and the highlight logic done at client side.

Given html table with id="stats" which means the highlights will be applied for this table's td.

```
<table id="stats">
    <tr>
        <td>83%</td>                                           
        <td>96%</td>
        <td>92%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>100%</td>                                           
        <td>94%</td>                                  
        <td>85%</td>                                            
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript with JQuery to perform the highlights.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).ready(function() {
        // for each td element within elements whose id="stats" 
        $("#stats td").each(function() {
            // current td element
            var td = $(this);
            // do it once only
            var val = td.text().replace('%', '');

            td.css('background',  val > 80 && val <= 85    ? 'yellow' 
                                  : val > 90 && val <= 95  ? 'red'
                                  : val > 95 && val <= 100 ? 'green'
                                  : 'black'); // black is default
        });

    }); 
</script>
```